# angular directive exclude attribute if not set

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive for a button - sometimes the user will require a ng-click, and sometimes a ui-sref

```
<md-button ng-click="controller.ngClick" ui-sref="controller.uiSref">
```

obviously, only one of these can be set at once - but how can I "hide" the one that's not needed ?

If I supply ng-click, then I need the html to look like

```
<md-button ng-click="controller.ngClick">
```

and I supply ui-sref, it should look like

```
<md-button ui-sref="controller.uiSref">
```

is this possible with angular / directives ? Or should I create 2 directives, one of each type ?

Comment: You should use two elements, one for each directive.

Comment: Can make a simple directive that creates the button. Not really clear what determines which is used. Is it just an `if controller[property]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the most simple solution - to use additional "flag":

```
<md-button ng-click="controller.clickable ? controller.ngClick() : '';" ui-sref="!controller.clickable ? controller.uiSref : '';">
```

or, using *ng-if*:

```
<md-button ng-if="controller.clickable" ng-click="controller.ngClick()">
<md-button ng-if="!controller.clickable" ui-sref="controller.uiSref">
```

where *controller.clickable* - flag to switch between click and href.

Comment: yeah, thanks for this. I was trying to see if I could be a little more elegant and use something like element.removeAttr() .. but this will do.